# Invalid authorization specification error with Classic ASP accessing SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am getting the following error: Invalid authorization specification

I've narrowed down the error to my connection string. I have verified the server name, database, user & password are correct. Here is the string:

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=xxxxx.db.12345.hostedresource.com;Database=foo;UID=fooUser;PWD=fooPW"
```

The SQL server is hosted on Godaddy so I don't have access to its settings.

Please help, I've scoured the internet for a solution!

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what version of SQL server.

See [this site](http://connectionstrings.com/) for all the allowed connection strings - you will need to look at your version under the OLE DB driver.

Comment: That appears to be SQL Server 2005

Comment: Thank you for the link. I compared my connection string to their examples. The only item I was missing was Trusted_Connection=False; which I added. Unfortunately it did not change the result. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Scott - can you connect to the server from SSMS? Where have you specified the connection string?

Comment: Yes, I can use SSMS to connect using the same credentials. The connection string is specified in the code, I don't know what you mean by this latter question.

Comment: @Scott - try creating a file DSN with these credentials (control panel -> Admin Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)) and test it. Examine it and convert to a connection string.

Comment: Try swapping from `SQLOLEDB` for the Native Provider by using `Provider=SQLNCLI10` or `Provider=SQLNCLI`

Comment: I ran across this problem intermittently with a connection string that I set in a SSIS package.  Sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't.  It turns out I was connecting to a SQL Server 2005 and included a Provider=SQLNCLI10 and this appeared to be causing the connection problem.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

> Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=fooDB;Data Source=xxxxx.db.12345.hostedresource.com;User ID=fooUser;Password=fooPW;Persist Security Info=True